# Is resin printing correct for my needs & limitations?

Tags: resin

I'm considering buying my first 3D printer. The only place in my house where I have enough space is the garage, and I fear a PLA printer will suffer from the possible temperature differences I may have there.

For this reason (And also the fact that it seems smoother) i'm considering buying a resin printer (like the Elegoo Mars), but I wanted to know if the fact it will be in a garage could be a bad idea? I imagine resin printing is far less sensible to temperature variations, but I may be wrong.

I will only print as a hobby, probably some figurines for me and my kids to paint, or small hardware pieces / boxes for electronic components.

Comment: I'm considering the same thing. I eagerly await responses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Resin likes it warm and dark

Resins increase in viscosity at low temperatures, so having low temperatures may have bad effects on the prints. However, Resin also likes it dark, so if your garage has a temperature above about 10 °C and is dry enough to prevent condensation, then your garage would be a good place.

### Figurines and high detail models are a common use case for resin

It is near impossible to print miniatures for wargaming and similar in FDM, but resin printers are a very common type for this use case. Similarly, Cosplay props with a very high detail grade can benefit from being printed in resin, either directly or as an intermediate step to create a mold.

With the proper equipment, one could make flexible molds to cast wax positives which then can be used with the lost-wax-technique to create many high detailed metal copies of the printed first positive.

### Containers are a possible use case for resin

Resin prints are more brittle than FDM prints. While limited in size, such containers, just as much as casings for electronics, are a possible usecase. In fact, replacement casings for retro electronics (think SNES controllers or N64 Cartridges during restoration projects) are somewhat common, even though they have not the same sturdiness as the original ABS casings. Here, the high detail grade makes the cut.

### Tooling is a poor use case

Resin prints are very brittle and have little to no ductile movement. While I have used FDM-printed parts from PLA in a few projects to make adapters between machines and my shop vacuum as well as to create an aluminium bending tool, resin printed parts with their near to no flexibility are generally a poor use case to create hardware or tooling from.

Comment: Thanks for all the info! I should check the current temperature in the garage, to see if I would be able to print during the winter.

Comment: I just checked, the temperature is currently just above 12 degrees. It should be perfect then.

Comment: @MarcBrillault 10 is the absolute minimum, but you might want to take precautions against condensation nontheless.